# In d3.js How to adjust tooltip (up and down) based on the screen position?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was created a `geo map` using `d3.js`.In that i created a tooptip over each country.

Basically am creating tooltip while `mousemove` event.

### Code for Tooltip:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {  

    return tooltip
    .style("left",d3.event.pageX+"px")
    .style("top",d3.event.pageY+10+"px")
    .style("visibility", "visible")             

    .html(function() {

    return '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'
            +'<p style="font-weight:bold;">'+ d.properties.name +'</p>'
            +'<div>'+d.properties.tooltip+'</div></div>';                                                                               
       })   

})
```

My tooltip was working fine.I used `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` for getting current location.Basically am updating tooltip style `left` with `d3.event.pageX` and `top` with `d3.event.pageY`.

So far `tooltip` is coming below for each country.But i need display tooltip based the window position.

### For example:

If i `mousemove` the top placed countries like `United states` i need to display `tooltip` **below** the country.Suppose if i `mousemove` over the `Antarctica` i need to display `tooltip` **above** the country(Because `Antarctica` is the `bottom country` so that `tooltip` cant visible properly in the page)

So my problem is i need to change the tooltip postion based on the windows postion.Please help me solve this.I update my fiddle link below.Kindly take a look.

Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to calculate, If the mouse is reaching the bottom, If mouse position is at bottom then set top value as needed.
Below is the code

```
.style("top",function(){
                    if(current_position[1]+70 > 500){
                        return current_position[1]-50+"px";
                    }else{
                        return current_position[1]+100+"px"
                    }
                })
```

Hope you got it,
If not ask me for more...

Comment: Thank you so much @saikiran.vsk. Got a solution :)